# Can Gerrit Trigger Plugin send +1 Verify vote to Gerrit commit without triggering Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I added a file to the Forbidden Files so that Jenkins jobs won't be started by the Gerrit trigger plugin when a commit only includes Forbidden Files, however in this situation I need to add +1 verify label to my commit.

I see in the Gerrit trigger server configuration/Gerrit Reporting Values section, it has "Not Built" result but it did not work, no verify voted will be sent.